# Using index in Update Clause on Apache Ignite Sql Query

Tags: sql, indexing, ignite

How do I choose a Index to use on an UPDATE Clause like this. I need to specify the index of the columns used in WHERE clause?

```
UPDATE
    DB.MY_TABLE
SET
    BLOCKED = true,
    HOME = '1',
    WORK = '2',
WHERE
    NAME = 'Me';
```

The column 'NAME' is indexed with INDEX_NAME but the other columns are also indexed with other indexes. I wanted to do somenthing like that to specify which index I am using (Which seems to work just on SELECT clauses):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    DB.MY_TABLE
USE INDEX(INDEX_NAME)
WHERE
    NAME = 'Me';
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. Having said that, I'm surprised it would pick the wrong index.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know for sure what index is being used, since the "explain" does not work for UPDATE clauses, just for SELECTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Ignite executes these queries - at the time of writing this post - is by spliting the query into two parts:

1. `SELECT` with the same condition as specified in the original query.
2. Iterate over the `SELECT` results and update each record as specified in the `SET` clause.

It's usually easy to guess how the `SELECT` part will look like based on the original query. In your case, I'm pretty sure `SELECT * FROM DB.MY_TABLE WHERE Name = 'Me'` is the query that will be executed.

I would just check that `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM DB.MY_TABLE WHERE Name = 'Me'` uses the index you want it to use and then trust the system to do the `UPDATE` correctly.